# TypeError: 'TwitterDictResponse' object is not callable on Twitter library for Python

Tags: python, api, twitter

I installed Twitter library for Python with `pip install Twitter` and I am trying to replicate an example from [here](https://github.com/ideoforms/python-twitter-examples/blob/master/twitter-search.py). This is my code:

```
config = {}
execfile("config.py", config)

twitter = Twitter(auth = OAuth(config["access_key"], config["access_secret"], config["consumer_key"], config["consumer_secret"]))

query = twitter.search.tweets(q = "lazy dog")
print query
```

The `config.py` file contains the keys, where `XxXxX` are my own keys from dev Twitter:

```
consumer_key = "XxXxXxxXXXxxxxXXXxXX"
consumer_secret = "xXXXXXXXXxxxxXxXXxxXxxXXxXxXxxxxXxXXxxxXXx"
access_key = "XXXXXXXX-xxXXxXXxxXxxxXxXXxXxXxXxxxXxxxxXxXXxXxxXX"
access_secret = "XxXXXXXXXXxxxXXXxXXxXxXxxXXXXXxXxxXXXXx"
```

However, I have this error:

`TypeError: 'TwitterDictResponse' object is not callable`

Which I couldn't find anywhere on Google. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy/pasted your code on my laptop and it works perfectly for me with Python 2 and Python 3 (with slight modifications in this case).
I am using the 'twitter-1.17.1' library.

Comment: It seems that something goes wrong with it when I use it with Python Flask in a server and not directly in console. You are right that if I run only this code in IDE, it will return the results. I will investigate it more. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as you should not give the variable the same name as the library, your authorization function appears wrong, and it's better to code in components:

```
import twitter

config = {}
execfile("config.py", config)

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(config["access_key"], config["access_secret"], config["consumer_key"], config["consumer_secret"])

twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

query = twitter_api.search.tweets(q="lazy dog", counts=100)
```

That should work. Interesting approach to put parameters in a dictionary.